# MySql select with like and give a weight based on number of substrings found

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-like, regexp-like

I have a table (books)

```
id, title
```

I made a select with REGEXP match

```
select title 
from books 
where title REGEXP "word1|word2|...|wordn"
```

How can I achieve how many words I found in title in order to obtain a query like that?

```
select title, numberofwordsfound 
from books 
where title REGEXP "word1|word2|...|wordn"
```

Thanks in advance to everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a derived table to list the words, then aggregation:

```
select b.id, b.title, count(*) no_matches
from books b
inner join (
    select 'word1' word
    union all select 'word2'
    union all select 'word3'
) w on b.title like concat('%', w.word, '%')
group by b.id, b.title
order by no_matches desc
```

In very recent versions of MySQL, you can use the `VALUES()` row-constructor to enumerate the words, which shortens the query:

```
select b.id, b.title, count(*) no_matches
from books b
inner join (values(row('word1'), row('word2'), row('word3')) b(word)
    on b.title like concat('%', w.word, '%')
group by b.id, b.title
order by no_matches desc
```

This assumes that the "words" are just that - words. If they contain regular expression patterns, they you need to use a regex match instead of `like`:

```
on b.title regexp w.word
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick with `regexp_replace()` and capture groups:

```
select title,
       length(regexp_replace(title, '(word1|word2|...|wordn)', '$1x')) - length(title) as num_matches
from books 
where title REGEXP 'word1|word2|...|wordn';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30ddf6869d53e3ae5d0032b09ee228b7) is a db<>fiddle.